# TypeError Observable.concat is not a function

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I need concat an array of observables and then subscribe to them

there's the function

```
let arrayObservable: Array<Observable<any>> = new Array<Observable<any>>();

products
 .forEach(product => {
    arrayObservable.push(this.service.delete(product));
});
Observable.concat(arrayObservable)
 .subscribe(response => {
    console.log(response)
})
```

Comment: Did you inspect what `Observable` is?

Comment: Did you import it? What RxJS version you have? Have a look at this https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3798

Comment: the version of rxjs is the 5.1

Comment: with merge function i retrive the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`concat` and `merge` are static functions in `rxjs`. They are not on `Observable`.

Example:

```
import { concat, of} from "rxjs";
const n1 = of(1,2,3);
const n2 = of(4,5,6);
const cc = concat(n1, n2);
cc.subscribe(d=> console.log(d));
```